# Xcode 5 – iOS 7– Has no constraints in Storyboard Based Application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, autolayout, uistoryboard

Am getting  the following message in Storyboard based  application(ios & and xCode 5)
“The selected views have no constraints. At build time explicit left, top, width, and height constraints will be generated for the view.”

[image].

Comment: Erm - probably because you are using auto layout and have not added any constraints ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode 5, interface builder will not add any constraints automatically. You could add the required constraints manually. In the bottom of window there is an option for that. You can choose `Add Missing constraints` or `Reset to Suggested constraints`. Otherwise add each constraints one by one.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Either add some constrains or untick "Use Auto Layout" from "File inspector"

[image]

Image taken from [here](http://www.goodbyehelicopter.com/2012/02/arggh-xcode-4-3-auto-layout-is-on-by-default-how-to-turn-off-auto-layout/).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to add constraints to the image. For that click the 2nd button from the left (4 set of buttons), that is in bottom right corner of your screen shot. I think you get it.